# Temperature of an aerosol can

Tags: gas-laws

Hey guys I just had a quick question regarding the temperature of a dust off can or other aerosol cans containing compressed gas. It is if I have a dust off can and I were to spray some gas from it, why would the temperature of the gas inside the can decrease. Is it because there is a reduction in both pressure and volume, or id it for some other reasons. I am probably gonna say that the reduction in pressure and volume cause a decrease in temperature as demonstrated by Gay-Lussac, but I am not sure. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

The air that remains in the can after some of the air has been expelled has just experienced something approximating an adiabatic reversible expansion.  It did work to push the expelled air out of the can, and, by the first law of thermodynamics, its internal energy (and thus its temperature) have decreased.